# How do you search through each row of a dataframe and copy values from this dataframe into another dataframe if certain conditions are met?

Tags: python, pandas

```
csvfile = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name','Age','Job','Qualifications'])

emptydataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name','Age'])

row1 = next(csvfile.iterrows())

for index, row1 in csvfile.iterrows():
    if row['Name'] == Jon:
```

Comment: [Do not iterate over a dataframe.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/4909087)

Comment: emptydataframe = csvfile[csvfile['Name'] == Jon][['Name', 'Age']]

Comment: What I don't understand is how to select a row based on values in the current row and next row and possibly next row etc. A sequence of values

Comment: Then provide more information in your question, so we can understand what you mean.

Comment: Why would you want to do that ?

Comment: Because I'm looking for sequences in the dataframe. So I want to extract any row where lets say 'Age' in the current row is 30 and the next row 'Age' is 40. If this sequence appears then copy the current row 'Name' and 'Age', so 'Jon', '30' into the empty first row of emptydataframe and continue to look for these sequences throughout the csvfile

Comment: You could use DataFrame.diff() for that. And select all rows where the diff value satisfies your criteria (e.g. is positive).

Comment: What about strings? Say I wanted to select a row where the current row is 'Jon' and next is 'Sam' and every time this pattern could been seen extract the column values for current row, eg. 'Name', 'Age', 'Occupation'

Comment: I have explained it a bit better in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55680822/how-do-you-search-through-a-row-row-1-of-a-csv-file-but-search-through-the-ne?noredirect=1#comment98052260_55680822