# How do you search through a row (Row 1) of a CSV file, but search through the next row (Row 2) at the same time?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Imagine there are THREE columns and a certain number of rows in a dataframe. First column are random values, second column are Names, third column are Ages.

I want to search through every row (First Row) of this dataframe and find when value 1 appears in the first column. Then simultaneously, I want to know that if value 1 does indeed exist in the column, does value 2 appear in the SAME column but in the next row.

If this is the case. Copy First Rows, Value, Name And Age into an empty dataframe. Every time this condition is met, copy these rows into an empty dataframe

```
EmptyDataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns['Name','Age'])
csvfile = pd.DataFrame(columns['Value', 'Name', 'Age'])


row_for_csv_dataframe = next(csv.iterrows())

for index, row_for_csv_dataframe in csv.iterrows():
    if row_for_csv_dataframe['Value'] == '1':

    # How to code this:
    # if the NEXT row after row_for_csv_dataframe finds the 'Value' == 2
    # then copy 'Age' and 'Name' from row_for_csv_dataframe into the empty DataFrame.
```

Comment: Can you provide an example data set, the code you have right now, its output as well as the expected output? That would make it much easier to reproduce and help to solve your problem.

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: There is still no sample data and expected output. Hard to answer without making assumptions.

Comment: Just the use the sample below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a dataframe `data` like this:

```
   Value  Name  Age
0      1  Anne   10
1      2  Bert   20
2      3  Caro   30
3      2  Dora   40
4      1  Emil   50
5      1  Flip   60
6      2  Gabi   70
```

You could do something like this, although this is probably not the most efficient:

```
iterator1 = data.iterrows()
iterator2 = data.iterrows()
iterator2.__next__()
for current, next in zip(iterator1,iterator2):
  if(current[1].Value==1 and next[1].Value==2):
    print(current[1].Value, current[1].Name, current[1].Age)
```

And would get this result:

```
1 Anne 10
1 Flip 60
```

Comment: How would I copy this print into an empty dataframe?

Comment: I would look up the pandas documentation. There are different ways. Maybe `pd.DataFrame([current[1].Name, current[1].Age], columns=['Name','Age'])`?